# Не заносятся данные в таблицу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Эта строка почему то не зносит в БД данные.. если проверяю `$result2` на `TRUE` - выдает `FALSE`
при том что БД включена, имя таблицы прописанно правильно переменные все существуют

```
$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO coalitions (name, avatar, creators, stat) VALUES ('$name', '$logotip', '$creatorid', '$stat')",$db);//заносим в базу сообщение
```

**Добавлено:**

поля таблицы - `id` - авто инкремент - `int9; name varchar225; avatar varchar225; creators varchar225; stat int1 дефаулт 0;`

Comment: Посмотри текст ошибки echo mysql_error();

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Выложи весь код, проблема может быть как несоответствие данных или поле unique стоит и ты вводишь тоже самое. Весь код выложи?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YEUtGf7V вот полный код с начала получения переменных через POST и до проблемной строки

Comment: ничего не выдает к сожалению..

Comment: он вобще ничего не хочет заносить в таблицу! поставил для теста другие переменные - тоже

Comment: Попробуй следующее:

- выставь error_reporting(E_ALL);

- $db точно идентификатор соединения с бд?

- распечатай запрос, попробуй его выполнить через консоль.

Comment: пробовал все тоже вобще не отзывается как будто запроса и не было(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй сделать сам запрос непосредственно в консоль базы, т.е. "чистый" SQL-код с предполагаемыми значениями и посмотри. Хотя код в плане синтаксиса чист от ошибок - я подозреваю, что тип полей (либо их длина) не соответствуют тем данным, которые пытаются в них записать. Выложи распечатку команды `DESCRIBE coalitions;` - посмотрим, какие типы полей используются - может там `name` определено как `datetime`.. И вообще, напиши нам все значения данных, какие пытается скрипт записать в таблицу.

UPD: Строчка 23

```
$creatorid = $myrow['id'];
```

Значение `$myrow['id']` уже "пустое" в этой строке. Поэтому распечатай все значения данных, которые должны быть записаны в таблицу, перед SQL-запросом, а именно:

```
echo $name;
echo $logotip;
echo $creatorid;
echo $stat;
```

Comment: вот скрин таблицы http://y.jp0.ru/opt/1/8b4155a17cdeed118c4a48b97e6f7da.jpg
и переменные все в норме.. имеют тип String

Comment: Дело, как я уже упомянул, скорее всего не в таблице, а в том, что переменная `$creatorid` является пустой.
Распечатая ее через `echo $creatorid;` или вообще выведи строку SQL-запроса на экран, просто для отладки:

    echo "INSERT INTO coalitions (name, avatar, creators, stat) VALUES ('$name', '$logotip', '$creatorid', '$stat'";

перед тем, как ее реализовать в `mysql_query`

Comment: Как оказалось не с одним этим скриптом проблемы - перестали работатьи другие скрипты где естькоманда ИНСЕРТ - при том что изменению они не подвергались просто как будто команда ИНсерт отключилась...

Comment: Я все понимаю, но когда пытаешься делать `INSERT`, ведь ЧТО-ТО пишет в ответ?! Я имею ввиду ошибку - может стоит привести ее здесь? Ну хорошо, вводим команду `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`, где вместо `'root'@'localhost'` подставить надо своего юзера и хост (возможно и оставить `localhost` - зависит от конфигурации твоего хостинга или если локально всё). Что пишет? Может у юзера нет прав на `INSERT`?

Answer (score 2):

Все нашел! У меня в таблице 6 полей - 1 id с автоинкрементом - 2 name 3 avatar 4 creators 5 users 6 stat - 1е идет автоинкремент - 6е у него есть значение по умлочанию! - если я вбиваю данные полностью в запросе - заполняю 2 3 4 и 5 поля то запрос проходит если к примеру я заполняю только одно или два то запрос не проходит! Раньше так не было а теперь такое почему?

Comment: Все же немного нелегко ответить на "почему", не имея параметров таблицы и базы в целом. Почитай на тему `UPDATE` вместе с `skip attributes`. Точно сказать почему что-то не так у тебя с базой, увы, дистанционно не получается у меня.

Comment: ну к примеру база там ячейки id1 id2 id3 & id4 у них нет значениий по умолчанию, я делаю запрос тип "INSERT INTO mayabaza (id1,id2,id3) VALUES ('53','22','25')"; и он не проходит при этом ни ошибки ничего не пишет!! но если я указываю как заполнитьвсе 4 поля вот так "INSERT INTO mayabaza (id1,id2,id3,id4) VALUES ('53','22','25',''1')"; то все окей! если ставлю для id4 "по умолчанию" то 1й вариант тоже проходит.. аналогично с любым другим полем.